# Matlab: Detecting alternating colors in regularly shaped objects

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have an object that looks like the following:

[image]

In this image, I'd like to be able to say, going from top down, I'd like to be able to output "purple, red, purple, red, purple, red, purple."

Now, here are the general symptoms I incur (as the above image is just an example):

1. The main object is not always oriented on a clear axis. It could, be vertical, horizontal, anywhere in between.
2. Purple will always be the main background
3. Red will be the overlay
4. The overlay won't be so clearly defined like the resistor bands on a resistor. It will be more noisy as in this example.

The only approach I can think of is drawing a line through the chromosome and picking up what color comes out in that line, kind of like a barcode scanner. However, I'd like to do this in a completely unsupervised manner.

How do I do this? I'm trying to do this in Matlab.

Here is my current code to try to do it using PCA as one of the answers suggested:

```
rgbImage = label2rgb(temp);
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);

redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
blueChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 3);
listOfRGBValues = double(reshape(rgbImage, rows * columns, 3));
coeff = pca(listOfRGBValues);
transformedImagePixelList = listOfRGBValues * coeff;
pca1Image = reshape(transformedImagePixelList(:,1), rows, columns);
pca2Image = reshape(transformedImagePixelList(:,2), rows, columns);
pca3Image = reshape(transformedImagePixelList(:,3), rows, columns);
```

However, this code, inspired by [this file](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/101126/pca_image.m), doesn't allow me to "walk the major axis length" to read the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  First you can use PCA to find the major axis of the blob.  You can then walk the major axis and measure the change in color.  I would suggest using a color space like HSV or HSL instead of RGB because those spaces put changes in brightness but not color in another dimension whereas RGB conflates brightness and color.  Then you'll get a plot like this:

```
red:                      x xx          xx xx
between red and purple:    x    xx   x    x
purple:                           xxx xx
```

Median filtering can help with the outliers within red or purple segments while preserving the transition areas.  You can then do K-means clustering to find the 2 values for red and purple.  However, I would toss out outliers before clustering; you may also need more than 2 clusters.

Comment: I've done what you said, but I'm not able to walk the major axis length.

Comment: Ah that's probably a chunk of code that would take a while to code up and debug. Another alternative is to find the major axis and compute it's angle relative to the y axis and then rotate the image in the opposite direction. Then you can just walk straight down!